# Call to undefined method Michelf\Markdown::isDeferred() in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5

I am going to use michelf/php-markdown package in my Laravel 5.2 application.
To install this package I added `"michelf/php-markdown": "~1.6.0"` to `composer.json` file and then I ran `composer update` command.
After this, I changed `app.php` file and added `Michelf\Markdown::class` to Providers array and `'Markdown' => Michelf\Markdown::class` to aliases array.

But when I want to use this class:

```
public function store($request)
{
    $title = $request->title;
    $text= $request->text;
    $transformedText = Markdown::defaultTransform($text);
    dd($transformedQuestion);
}
```

I face this error:

```
FatalErrorException in C:\wamp\www\projects\stackoverflow\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php line 119:  

Call to undefined method Michelf\Markdown::isDeferred()
```

Is my way to install a package in Laravel wrong?

Answer (score 8):

I think it was my misunderstand about providers in Laravel.
I removed`Michelf\Markdown::class` from Providers array in `app.php` file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using inertiajs with Laravel 8 and I noticed that I had added this `\App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,` into providers array in config/app.php which needs to be added in Http/Kernel.php `$middlewareGroups` array. Once I did that it fixed the issue.